# berberis vulgaris vs berberis aristata

Tags: spices, herbs, asian-cuisine, driedherbs

I was reading about zershek (dried `berberis vulgaris` fruit) in Iran and being Indian , I searched if this is grown in India. I found that `berberis aristata` is grown in Himalayas and it's fruit is edible too.

Does anyone know if I can use  `berberis aristata` in cooking ? Can it replace `berberis vulgaris` ?

Answer (score 2):

The [Genus Berberis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berberis) commonly known as barberry, is a large genus of deciduous and evergreen shrubs found throughout temperate and subtropical regions of the world (apart from Australia). This [Genus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genus) containing both Species:

- [Berberis Aristate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berberis_aristata)
- [Berberis Vulgaris](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berberis_vulgaris)

and berries of [both](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berberis_aristata#Uses) of [these](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berberis_vulgaris#Culinary_uses) have not only culinary uses but medicinal uses in folk medicine.

Zereshk (زرشک) is just the Persian name of the Vulgaris variety and they **both can be used for cooking without changing the recipe** except that the Iranian variety mostly comes in the dried form due to climate, whereas the Arista variety might come fresh instead of dried, so adapt your recipe to account for the extra amount of water the fresh variety might contain.

Comment: Thnx for input. However, according to wiki link : `Zereshk is widely used in cooking, imparting a tart flavor to chicken dishes. It is usually cooked with rice, called zereshk polo, and provides a nice meal with chicken.` hence vulgaris have culinary use. Also, my question is still not answered. `Does anyone know if I can use  berberis aristata in cooking ? Can it replace berberis vulgaris ?`

Comment: @Breaking Benjamin The Wikipedia entry for Berberis Aristate states the fruit may be eaten raw and the root can yield an alcholic drink. I see no reason given why you could not also cook the the fruit

Comment: @BreakingBenjamin My apologies for not being clearer. Edited.